# how to arrange icons in TSF Shell?

Tags: launcher

I'm using TSF Shell, which allows you to drag your application icons around in an overlapping manner. But how do I tell TSF Shell to automatically arrange my icons neatly in rows using a grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'lasso' option for that. It works real cool.